# Access website running in IIS server from Remote machine

Tags: iis-7, web

Please help me out regarding this. I am running a website in my IIS 7 server, I am able to access it from local. But I am not able to access it from remote machine. I have gone through some forums and set permission in my windows firewall also. I am using the public IP. Same thing is working for tomcat server, but not working for IIS server. Please help me.

Comment: are you on a local network, or the internet?

Comment: ah. Are you using a hosting service or is it your own machine?

Comment: I am using my machine only. I created a sample web application and deployed in Tomcat and its accessible from the remote machine. But when I use the IIS server, I am not able to access it. I checked with firewall also. I cant get the idea, what is causing the problem.

Comment: Did you change any settings in the IIS server? Or did you just paste stuff into your wwwroot?